# text field name should be unique

Tags: java, jsp, dynamic, textbox

I am working on a project where the client's requirement is to add a dynamic text box. I made the dynamic text box but I'm not getting the unique name of the text box.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addfieldset() {

        var namefieldset = document.getElementById("name").cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById("names").appendChild(namefieldset);
    }
    function deletefieldset(e) {
        var namefieldset = e.parentNode;
        namefieldset.parentNode.removeChild(namefieldset);
    }
</script>
<body>
    <%! public static int i = 1;%>
    <% if (i > 0) { %>
    <div id="names"><div id="name"><% out.print(i);%>Name: <input name="namefield<%= i%>" type="text"/><a href="#" onclick="deletefieldset(this)">delete</a></div></div>

    <input id="addnamebtn" type="button" value="Add Name" onclick="addfieldset()"/>

    <% i++;
}%>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different codes. The key is to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

I.e. you have to change the name of the new text field in the `addfieldset()` function (which means you have to have a counter, how many text fields there already is).

Answer (score 0):

try this JavaScript and HTML

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var i = 0;
 function generateRow() {
  i++;
  var d = document.getElementById("div");
  d.name = "food";
  d.innerHTML += "<p>name"+i+" :<input type='text' name='name" + i + "' /> <a href='#' onclick='deletefieldset(this)'>delete</a></p>";
 }

 function deletefieldset(e) {
  var namefieldset = e.parentNode;
  namefieldset.parentNode.removeChild(namefieldset);
 }
 
 function onLoad() {
  generateRow();
    }
    window.onload = onLoad;
</script>
<body>
 <div id="div"></div>
 <p>
  <input type="button" id="addnamebtn" value="Add Name" onclick="generateRow()" />
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The java code in scriptlet is executed on the server side. Hence, cloning it again through Javascript will not execute the scriptlet again.

An another approach of what you are trying to achieve will be to store the count variable in javascript.

```js
var count = 1;

function addfieldset() {
  count++;
  var namefieldset = document.getElementById("name").cloneNode(true);
  var textField = namefieldset.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  textField.setAttribute("name", "namefield" + count);
  textField.value = "";

  document.getElementById("names").appendChild(namefieldset);
}

function deletefieldset(e) {
  var namefieldset = e.parentNode;
  namefieldset.parentNode.removeChild(namefieldset);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="names">
    <div id="name">
      <span>Name:</span>
      <input name="namefield1" type="text" />
      <a href="#" onclick="deletefieldset(this)">delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input id="addnamebtn" type="button" value="Add Name" onclick="addfieldset()" />
</body>
```

Comment: @rahim *Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.*